# Is using prefetch_related to retrieve related (parents, children pages) possible In Wagtail Pages?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

The problem I am facing is duplicate number of queries which makes the app slow when using get_parent() or get_children() on Page model. which also increase if the parent page has an image file that is used in the template.

so I am looking for a way to prefetch_related pages without making a foriegn key relation.

let us say I have a TvSeries Page model and an Episode Page model:

```
class TvSeries(Page):
    name = models.CharField()
    producer = models.CharField()

    subpage_types = ['Episode']
```

```
class Episode(Page):
    title = models.CharField()
    number = models.CharField()
    parent_page_types = ['TvSeries']
```

Need to prefetch the TvSeries when querying the episode model! How to reduce the database calls? Is it possible to use prefetch and select related ? if yes how?. and if not, what is the solution to the increased number of queries?

Comment: Its only extend one model `Page` and dont have any special between `TvSeries` and `Episode`? Can you show model `Page`

Comment: I am using Wagtail CMS. Inheriting the page model which inherits from Django-treebeard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prefetch_related` cannot be used for parent/child page relations, because they do not use a standard Django `ForeignKey` relation - instead, Wagtail (and Treebeard) uses a `path` field to represent the tree position. This makes it possible to perform queries that can't be done efficiently with a `ForeignKey`, such as fetching all descendents (at any depth) of a page.

It should be noted that `prefetch_related` is not "free" - it will generate one extra query for every relation followed. Treebeard's query methods will usually be equal or better than this in efficiency - for example:

```
series = TvSeries.objects.get(id=123)
episodes = series.get_children()
```

will fetch a `TvSeries` and all of its episodes in two queries, just as a (hypothetical) `prefetch_related` expression would:

```
# fake code, will not work...
series = TvSeries.objects.filter(id=123).prefetch_related('child_pages')
```

However, one issue with `get_children` is that it will only return basic `Page` instances, so further queries are required to retrieve the specific fields from `Episode`. You can avoid this by using `child_of` instead:

```
series = TvSeries.objects.get(id=123)
episodes = Episode.objects.child_of(series)
```

Comment: The problem is when you have multiple of objects. Let say we want to retrieve the latest 30 episodes with their parents: latest_episodes = Episode.objects.all()[:30] >>> now you will have to do get_parent() or parent_of() for every episode. that is 30 db call add to that if the parent have image file then you will have more 30 db call. I am starting to think that the best solution is to make a ParentalKey or write my own raw query. thanks

Comment: I am also struggling with this

Comment: It's true that the tree structure allows some nifty things, but we need a simple parent lookup much more often... `prefetch_related` is not "free" but `select_related` translates into standard `JOIN`s -- as every page can have only 1 direct parent I also find it frustrating that a child page cannot get it's parent with one query. i think we'll be also adding a parent pointer id or similar...